# how to set auto wrap in Apache Poi (Excel File)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to set auto wrap text in Rows. How to do that in this code

```
Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
if(header is greater than 10){
wrap header text
}

Row row = sheet.createRow(count++);
if(row greater than 10){
wrap row text
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto wrap in apache POI (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676714/auto-wrap-in-apache-poi-excel)

Comment: `Excel` is a spreadsheet calculation application. So there is not any "row text". A row in a sheet contains of cells and text perhaps is cell content in those cells. And a cell may have [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html), where the [WrapText](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setWrapText-boolean-) property is set.